# shooting bullet based on an angle from a point

Tags: c++, math, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, trigonometry

what i am doing is scanning an area with a sprite of a straight line that i rotate 20 degrees back and forth

when i tap my action button i want to shoot a bullet in the direction of rotation of the sprite

i get the angle by doing a

```
sprite->getRotation();
```

and i have the point of my unit available, lets say it is (0,0)

i'm guessing i need to find a point on the line, but i don't know the math behind it.

is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you know the velocity of your bullet (pixels/second), let me assume you will call it `v`. That it takes `s` seconds to transverse your screen. And that `x` represents the position of your bullet at axis `x` (same to `y` variable), you can actualize both variables using this simple trigonometry:

```
x = 0; // initial position. You say that it start at (0,0)
y = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
   sleep(1);    // look in unistd.h
   x += v*cos(angle);  // include math.h
   y += v*sin(angle);  // angle in radian, of course
   // draw your sprite here, at (x, y)
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for. for some reason it worked for me when i switched the sin and cos on the x and y. thanks for pointing me in the right directions.